# minikube message: preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to deploy 2 services in minikube.I am doing this in a ubuntu VM, which has been assigned 4 CPUs and 20+ gb of memory.

I see this message on minikube dashboard:

```
preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
```

On some google search, it seems this is caused when resources are not sufficient.

But for both services, resources are as:

```
  resources:
      limits:
        cpu: '1'
        memory: 2Gi
      requests:
        cpu: '1'
        memory: 2Gi
```

Values seem well within what VM has been assigned.

What else can cause this issue?